# How to break beanshell script into functions & call them?

Tags: jmeter

Here below are my scenario:

1. I am using JMeter to generate loads
2. I have to read multiple .csv files and extracting values, then add some logic to it and then pass this data to Java functions (we have a jars files for that)
3. I am using a BeanShell script. But I don't want to write all the code into one file. As its become a very big file and hard to maintain.

Query: Is there any way to write these functions in multiple beanshell script?
Query: Is that possible to call these function written in different beanshell scripts?

Can you provide a sample code for this.

Comment: consider creating Java library and call it from your scripts. Or even better: custom Java samplers you can call with various arguments. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different  [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) to hold one file of beanshell scripts/functions by defining same script file

> Script File
>   Name of a file to be used as a JSR223 script

If you have different functions you can use similarly [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)

> Test Fragment is used in conjunction with the Include Controller and Module Controller.

Comment: Can you please give some example, that would be a great help!!   Here is what I am trying to do. for example                                          
        

1st Bean shell file, I defined a function                                                   int sum (int a, int b)
{
                return a+b;
}
2nd Bean shell file, I am trying to call it                                             int j = sum(2,3);
log.info("sum-------------"+j);